# Creating a *.local ssl certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates, apache-virtualhost

I am trying to set up a single SSL certificate that will make any *.local website work over https. I have all .local domains pointing back to my local machine. I use these when developing websites. A lot of new features (geo location, service workers etc.) require an SSL.

I believe that for recent versions of Chrome/Firefox, an old school self-signed certificate no longer works.

Below are the steps I have taken after following a combination of these guides:
https://deliciousbrains.com/https-locally-without-browser-privacy-errors/

https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2008/03/17/create-a-certificate-authority-and-certificates-with-openssl/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294589/creating-self-signed-certificate-for-domain-and-subdomains-neterr-cert-commo

Here is my config file:

```
#..................................
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default
[ CA_default ]
dir = /home/*****/Sites/root-ca
serial = $dir/serial
database = $dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir = $dir/certs
certificate = $dir/certs/cacert.pem
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem
default_days = 3000
default_md = sha256
preserve = no
email_in_dn = no
nameopt = default_ca
certopt = default_ca
policy = policy_match
copy_extensions = copyall
[ policy_match ]
countryName = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName = match
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048 # Size of keys
default_keyfile = key.pem # name of generated keys
default_md = md5 # message digest algorithm
string_mask = nombstr # permitted characters
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name Prompt string
#------------------------- ----------------------------------
0.organizationName = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
emailAddress = Email Address
emailAddress_max = 40
localityName = Locality Name (city, district)
stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min = 2
countryName_max = 2
commonName = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)
commonName_max = 64
# Default values for the above, for consistency and less typing.
# Variable name Value
#------------------------ ------------------------------
0.organizationName_default = *****
localityName_default = *****
stateOrProvinceName_default = *****
countryName_default = *****
emailAddress_default = *****
[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
[ v3_req ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
nsComment            = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = *.local
```

I first create a new certificate authority:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout private/cakey.pem -out certs/cacert.pem -days 3000 -config conf/caconfig.cnf
```

I have given the Common name here as my name

```
Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name) []:Jonathan Hodgson
```

The file `certs/cacert.pem` I then import into chromium's authorities which works without a problem.

I then create a certificate request:

```
openssl req -extensions v3_req -new -nodes -out local.req.pem -keyout private/local.key.pem -config conf/caconfig.cnf
```

I have given the Common name here as *.local

```
Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name) []:*.local
```

I then sign the request:

```
openssl ca -out certs/local.cert.pem  -config conf/caconfig.cnf -infiles local.req.pem
```

I add the files to my http config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/jonathan/Sites/%-2/public_html
    CustomLog /home/jonathan/Sites/access.log vhost_combined
    ErrorLog /home/jonathan/Sites/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/jonathan/Sites/%-2/public_html
    CustomLog /home/jonathan/Sites/access.log vhost_combined
    ErrorLog /home/jonathan/Sites/error.log
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /home/jonathan/Sites/root-ca/certs/local.cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/jonathan/Sites/root-ca/private/local.key.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted apache but I am still getting `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

I was under the impression that this was because I needed to add the subjectAltName to the config file which I have done.

Please let me know what I should do differently.

Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit**

I think the problem is to do with the wildcard. If I set the alternate_names to example.local and the Common name for the request to example.local, example.local shows as secure in both Chrome and Firefox.

I tried to set DNS.1 to `local` and DNS.2 to `*.local`, I then just got `ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT` in chrome and `SEC_ERROR_REUSED_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL` in firefox.  I definitely reset my serial file and my index file before generating the certificates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added SAN to the *CSR* but you didn't **tell `ca` to include extensions from the CSR** in the certificate. See
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate or the man page for `ca` [also on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/ca.html) at `copy_extensions`

EDIT: You *also* need to specify `x509_extensions` in the `ca` config, or equivalent but less convenient the commandline option `-extensions`, in either case pointing to a section that exists but can be empty if you don't want any CA-required extensions. I didn't notice this at first because I had never tried the case of extensions from CSR *only* and not config, which is unrealistic for most CAs. If you specify `copy_extensions` other than `none` (and the CSR has some) but don't specify `x509_extensions` then `ca` *does* put the extensions in the cert but *does not* set the cert version to v3 as is required by standards (like rfc5280) when extensions are present.

It's arguable if this is a bug; the manpage says `x509_extensions/extensions` controls the v3 setting, and by *not* saying any similar thing about `copy_extensions` implies that does not, but IMHO it's certainly a very suboptimal feature. EDIT: it is a bug and will be fixed but until then use the workaround, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394465/59699

HOWEVER: in my test, this didn't actually solve your problem. Even though the cert has `*.local` in SAN *and* CN and is (now) otherwise valid, my Firefox (53.0.2) and Chrome (59.0.3071.109) still reject it with SSL_ERROR_CERT_DOMAIN_ERROR and ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID respectively. I guessed they might not be excluding `local` from the normal 2+-level logic and tried `*.example.local`: Chrome does accept that, but Firefox doesn't. I also tried `*.example.org` and both Chrome and IE11 like *that* but still not Firefox (and of course assigning yourself names in real TLDs like `.org` is not the way DNS is supposed to work).

This has me stuck. With some work OpenSSL can be made to generate a cert containing almost anything you want, but what Firefox and Chrome will *accept* I do not know. I will try to look into that and update if I find anything.

---

<strike>I hope you mean</strike> you gave `*.local` as the CommonName only for the server CSR and NOT for the CA (self-signed) cert. If Subject names for CA and leaf certs are the same nothing will work reliably. EDIT: your edited Q confirms they were correctly different. Although it does not mention also specifying Country, State, and Organization as is required by the `ca` policy you used.

Note 'self-signed' is a term of art and means signed with the same *key*. Your CA cert is self-signed. Your server cert is signed by you yourself using your own key but it is *not* self-signed. Trying to apply instructions for a self-signed cert to a not-self-signed cert was part of your problem.

And Gilles point about md5 for the signature algorithm is also correct.

EDIT: 'resetting' serial (and index) for an `openssl ca` setup is a bad idea, unless you permanently discard the CA cert *and name* they were used for. The standards say a given CA must not issue more than one cert with the same serial value in the cert, and the serial file is the way `openssl ca` (and also `x509 -req`) implements this. 'Real' (public) CAs nowadays no longer use a simple counter but include entropy to block collision attacks on PKI -- google hashclash -- but this is not an issue for a personal CA like yours. I can readily believe a browser (or other relier) being unhappy if it sees multiple certs with the same serial and CA name, although I would NOT expect a browser to persistently store a leaf cert -- and thus see both the old and new ones in one process unless long-running -- unless you import it to the applicable store, including in Firefox if you make it a permanent 'exception'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I am not entirely sure how I add the copy_extentions.  Should this be part of my config file or a flag on one of the commands?  I used the common name *.local when generating the request.  The Common name for the authority (the first command I ran) I used my name

Comment: @JonathanHodgson: `copy_extensions` (s not t, spelling matters!) goes in the config file; that's why it's documented under the subheading 'Configuration File Options'. It goes in the section `ca` uses directly (not via reference) which in your case is `[CA_default]`

Comment: Thanks.  I have added `copy_extensions = copyall` to the [CA_default] section. Re run the commands, restarted apache, re-imported the authority cert into chrome and still have the issue.  Thanks for helping

Comment: thanks for clarifying what a self signed certificate is.  Is there anything else I should be changing as a result of my mistake?

Comment: @JonathanHodgson: on testing, yes; editing

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 , I have created an issue on Chromium's issue tracker [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=736715&can=2&q=wildcard%20ssl&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard certificates are not permitted for a top-level domain like `.local` or `.com` and they aren't accepted by Firefox or IE either. https://crbug.com/736715.

Answer (score 0):

At least one obvious problem is that you're creating a certificate signed with [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). MD5 has been deprecated for a while, and broken in certificates specifically since 2012. No reputable server has supported it in a while.

Change `default_md md5` to `default_md sha256`.

If you're following a tutorial that recommends MD5, throw it away, it's too old to be of any use.

Note that I haven't reviewed to see whether there are other problems. The server logs should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for looking over it. I have changed from md5 to sha256. Re-run all the commands and re-imported the CA certificate into chrome.  It's still not working

Comment: I also re-started apache

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the answers worked for me, but I managed to come up with a working Powershell script for my future needs:

```powershell
#openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout localhost-CA.pem -out localhost-CA.crt -subj '/emailAddress=<redacted>/O=<redacted>/CN=<redacted>/C=US' -extensions v3_ca -addext 'nsCertType=sslCA' # uncomment to generate a root CA cert.
'basicConstraints=CA:FALSE`
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth`
subjectAltName=IP.1:127.0.0.1,IP.2:::1,DNS:localhost' | Set-Content sign.conf
Invoke-Expression "openssl req -new -sha256 -key localhost.pem -out localhost.csr -subj '/emailAddress=<redacted>/O=<redacted>/CN=<redacted>/C=US' $((Get-Content sign.conf | ForEach-Object { "-addext '$_'" }) -join ' ')"
openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA localhost-CA.crt -CAkey localhost-CA.pem -CAcreateserial -out localhost.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -extfile sign.conf -extensions default
Remove-Item sign.conf
```

It passes the same extensions as were used to generate the CSR to the new certificate generation utility w/o having to mess with configuration files, as that to my taste is a bit too much for such a small thing, and the resulting certificate is V3.