# How to generate a self signed certificate from openssl having the SPIFFE URI

Tags: openssl, certificates, authorization

I have a requirement of generating a SPIFFY Cert from the openssl similar to this here [Local SSL Certificates in Chrom(e/ium) 63](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393601/local-ssl-certificates-in-chrome-ium-63) can any one suggest on what need to be added to generate the spiffe uri to the cert ?